# Java: alternative to null for special meaning

Tags: java

In Java every variable of a object derived type can be an instance of that type OR null - as far I know.

Is there an alternative? e.g. not an instance but also not null?

I need to represent a special state.

e.g. use it as a parameter in a search-function that can represent a regular value, a null for "empty" or a wildcard for "anything".

```
Integer n;
n = null;              // empty
n = new Integer (11);  // regular value
n = ????               // wildcard

search (some_list, n);
```

The type in the sample is Integer. But it should be generic. So no Integer.MAX would be of help.

I want to do it without any added "flag-variables" - if possible.

Comment: There's the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) but this is not going to be possible with pre-existing classes such as `java.lang.Integer`. Possible solution: wrap the value in another object that you write yourself, that has the capability of marking that it represents the special value.

Comment: Only `Optional<Integer>` or `OptionalInt` and seemingly you want to add a single bit to the class. As Integer is a final class there is extension possibility.

Comment: "Is there an alternative? e.g. not an instance but also not null?" no. You can either assign an instance (possibly of a subclass) or null, nothing else.

Comment: Maybe a custom generic type that holds the value but also can keep track of your states like empty and wildcard but it is hard to know based on the information given

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to assign anything that's not either a `null` value or an instance of the correct type to a reference variable.

But there's ways to simulate that.

Take a look at [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html), it provides an object that can be either absent (*very roughly* equivalent to `null`) or present (and have an actual value).

You could do something similar, but with 3 states by creating your own class, let's call it `SearchValue`:

```
public class SearchValue<T> {
  private final T value;
  private final boolean missing;
  private final boolean wildcard;

  private SearchValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.missing = false,
    this.wildcard = false;
  }

  private SearchValue(boolean isMissing) {
    this.value = null;
    this.missing = isMissing;
    this.wildcard = !isMissing;
  }

  public static <T> SearchValue<T> of(T value) {
    return new SearchValue<>(value);
  }

  public static <T> SearchValue<T> missing() {
    return new SearchValue(true);
  }

  public static <T> SearchValue<T> wildcard() {
    return new SearchValue(false);
  }

  public T getValue() {
    if (value == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("no value specified");
    }
    return value;
  }

  public boolean isValue() {
    return value != null;
  }

  public boolean isMissing() {
    return missing;
  }

  public boolean isWildcard() {
    return wildcard;
  }
}
```

Any `SearchValue` instance will return `true` on exactly one of `isValue`, `isMissing` or `isWildcard` (and only return successfully from `getValue()` when `isValue()` returns true).

Note that this can definitely be optimized (by reducing the flags to one field and/or making sure that there's only ever one missing or wildcard instance, since they are interchangable), but the general principle should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

No, a variable is either null, or points to an object of an appropriate type, there is no other possibility. However, you can achieve your goal by encapsulating your search term, e.g.

```
public class SearchTerm<T> {

    private final T value;

    public static final SearchTerm WILDCARD = new SearchTerm<Object>(new Object());

    public SearchTerm(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

To check what type of `SearchTerm` an instance represents

```
void doSearch(SearchTerm<String> searchTerm) {

    if (searchTerm == SearchTerm.WILDCARD) {
        // do a wildcard search

    } else if (searchTerm.getValue() == null) {
        // do whatever type of search this represents

    } else {     
        // search for items that match this term
        String searchTermValue = searchTerm.getValue(); 
    }
}
```